# Добавьте кнопку сортировки, при нажатии на которую - выполненные заметки будут вверху списка

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка

как написать кнопку сортировки по чекбоксам на jquery не представляю...

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   // запускаем скрипт после загрузки дома

$('#list-items').html(localStorage.getItem('listItems'));//в ul записываем значение ключа в хранилище
$('.add-items').submit(function(event)//уст. обработчик элементу add items
    {
        event.preventDefault();// Отключить событие по умолчанию
        var item = $('#todo-list-item').val(); // айтем присваеваем значение todolistitem

        if (item)  // if item!=false
        {

            $('#list-items').append("<li><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'/>" + item + "<a class='remove'>x</a><hr></li>");// в список записываем значение из инпута
            localStorage.setItem('listItems', $('#list-items').html());//добавляеям в хранилище 
            $('#todo-list-item').val(""); //очищаем инпут

        }
    });
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function() //вешаем обработчик на док 
    {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) // если элемент checked 

        {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked'); //снимаем 
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); // вешаем
        }
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('completed');//возвращает родителя текущего элемента.накидываем на него класс комплитэд
        localStorage.setItem('listItems', $('#list-items').html()); //
    });
```